# What do I need to learn to contribute to a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, rust, julia

After reading [These Weeks in Rust](http://cmr.github.io/blog/2013/11/09/these-weeks-in-rust/), I felt overwhelmed and was reminded of how much I have yet to learn in this field. But, I feel like I will never get to a point where I can make contributions to a programming language. Say that I wanted to go from "oh I made a Rails app or two" to "I committed changes to Rust/Julia/whatever".

How long would it take me to make that jump? What do I need to learn? Can I just jump straight in?

Comment: Just jump straight in; feel free to start with something small (e.g. [tiny typo fixes are good!](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/10225)), or one of [these issues](https://wiki.mozilla.org/GNOME_Outreach_December2013#Contributions_for_Rust) (that list is a curated version of the ["easy" bugs](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues?labels=E-easy&page=1&state=open) for Rust). (That's Rust specific, but it applies generally, most projects will have a tag indicating bugs that are easy or beginner-friendly.) Also, the relevant IRC channels are good places to ask questions if you get stuck...

Comment: ... e.g. Rust uses [#rust](http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust) and [#rust-internals](http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust-internals) on irc.mozilla.org (and some others like #rust-gamedev and #rust-osdev). I'm sure Julia has channel(s) too.

Answer (score 2):

The fast and easy way to get a Pull Request merged is to find and fix a typo in the documentation or an error message.

If you want a more significant contribution and don't have a clear idea about what, I think you should just start following the project in as many channels as you have time for. See what fixes are contributed and what kind of problems people are reporting. Look for small suggested improvements others haven't gotten around to yet. Try to read part of the codebase to familiarize yourself with how it works, and find something that annoys you and others, that you understand how works.

The main motivation for those reading your comments is probably not to help you become a better programmer, but to improve the project. You will have to be prepared for comments from people that did not understand your proposals or your motivation. In some cases the developers will take your PR as a suggestion and commit a modified implementation without including your commit in the project history. Some contribute to fix a problem they have, others to have something to show off. It is hard for the developer to know if they should fix issues with your code himself or help you improve the PR in several iterations.